# How to open a project in WebStorm, using the command line (Windows 10)

Tags: command-line, webstorm, command-prompt

I would like to open WebStorm from the command line.

My goal is, when I have navigated to the right directory on my PC, to use a command, which opens the current directory as a project in WebStorm.

Comment: AFAIK there is no special launcher/script that comes with WebStorm for Windows platform (it only exist for Mac/Linux). But you can create it yourself -- some `wstorm.cmd` where you specify full path to the `webstorm.exe` (or webstorm64.exe if you are using 64-bit Java) and **full path** to your project folder as a parameter -- IDE will either open existing project there (if it exists -- based on `.idea` subfolder presence and content) or will create brand new project from those files.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne.. :)
Do you know of any guide to setup this configuration.? a tutorial or something.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax to open a project from command line on Windows is `path/to/WebStorm.exe path/to/your/project` - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/working-with-webstorm-features-from-command-line.html#d279626e72. You can add `%WebStorm installation directory%/bin` to your system %PATH% to be able to run WebStorm using `WebStorm` command instead of entering a full path to exe.

To open current directory as a project, you can (in principle) just run `WebStorm .`. But this doesn't currently work ([IDEA-108586](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108586)). You can try using `WebStorm.bat .` instead

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me recently on my MBP-M2. When I tried to open webstorm from the terminal, I received an error stating that webstorm is not a command. I fixed it by performing the following steps:

1. Press the shift key twice to bring up the quick search menu.
2. I then looked up 'command line lanchuer' and clicked on it.
3. I continued by pressing OK on the next window.
4. It will ask for system access permission; grant it.

It worked post this fix.

[image: Search command line launcher]

[image]